# nutch indexer FileNotFoundException: data does not exist

Tags: indexing, solr, nutch

I'm running nutch to crawl and index for solr. When running bin/nutch, I get the following error:

```
Indexer: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/opt/nutch/crawl/linkdb/current/linkdb-merge-1124746471/data does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:402)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:255)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1073)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:572)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

So, it complains that: /opt/nutch/crawl/linkdb/current/linkdb-merge-1124746471/data does not exist.
However, /opt/nutch/crawl/linkdb/current/linkdb-merge-1124746471/part00000/data does exist.
How can such discrepancy happen? i.e. where can I configure the indexing process so the indexer can find the files created by the previous step?

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The folder `.../linkdb/current/linkdb-merge-1124746471/` needs to be removed. It's a temporary folder from a "invertlinks" or "mergelinkdb" job. It's not in the right place: should be `.../linkdb/linkdb-merge-1124746471/`. This may happen if instead of `.../linkdb/` a job is called with `.../linkdb/current/`, since there are no restrictions how the linkdb is named.

Comment: Indeed I've emptied the content of both directories: linkdb and crawldb, ran nutch again and this time it worked as intended. Thanks!